# Anchor not working in IE7 via redirect (spring-mvc, jsp)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, internet-explorer-7, anchor

So for this project I am doing I have a page which generates content via clickable buttons. The button posts the form to my controller and the controller acts on the button that has been clicked. To show what was changed a redirect will occur (form in the session) with an anchor included. A little piece of javascript will then go to anchor which is in the link (eg. website/add/picture#123). This works fine in pretty much every browser except Internet Explorer 7.. I found out this has to do with an input field of file type.. Because if I remove the input field, then even IE7 will nicely scroll to the anchor..

Does anyone have any idea why this behaviour occurs?

If it's unclear please tell me and I'll provide more details..

Thanks a lot,
Davey

Comment: This may be way off-topic, but why not just use AJAX and edit the DOM in-place instead of reloading the page and jumping to some location in the page?  You can send files as part of an AJAX call.

Comment: I think you're right on that, but it would take quite a lot of code in javascript to produce a likewise result? I'm not very sure about it, but I will do some more investigation on AJAX and sending data.. thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. I didn't manage to solve the input type=file bug.. I suppose it's just an IE7 bug. I made a work around to put the input field on a popup. A lot of overhead but it is working pretty well now